# Estimate a series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

I'm stuck on a step in a proof. Does there exist a constant $C$ such that

$\sum_{l=0}^{\infty} [1+(t+lb)^2]^{-\alpha}\leq Ct^{-2\alpha}$

uniformly in $t>0$, where $ b>0, \alpha >1$ are fixed.

Comment: what is $\alpha?$

Comment: @zhw. Sorry, I have updated the question.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $t^{1-2\alpha}$ on the right?

Answer (score 0):

No.  Intuitively, if $t$ is huge, all the terms until $lb$ is about $t$ will be about $t^{-2\alpha}$ so for any proposed $C$ we just take $t$ much larger than $\frac Cb$.